# How to get all wall post of given public page in facebook without login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on one application where i need all posts with images of given public page in facebook. This should be working without user login. I have tried many solution but some doesn't provide full data with images and some asking for login.

Also how can i get long-lived access token without login or without $sesssion?

In short i pass one name of public page and as result i want all posts of it. But without user login.

```
    $page = 'page_name_here';
    $accessToken = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.APP_ID.'&client_secret='.APP_SECRET.'&grant_type=client_credentials');
    $data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page.'/feed?'.$accessToken);
```

Above code works fine but it doesn't provide image or post links

Result:

```
{"data":[{"message":"Delhi Convener Dilip Kumar Pandey addresses media on NDMC official MM Khan's Murder \n\nWatch and Share widely - https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Mw6qwZJz928","created_time":"2016-05-24T11:14:39+0000","id":"290805814352519_854949184604843"}],"paging":{"previous":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.6\/290805814352519\/feed?limit=1&since=1464088479&access_token=189770684754664|IC8JllfI0pjcDAx3lj7rSlAdPNw&__paging_token=enc_AdDbZCIZC3RToSKiDH1DKImBZBQ5Rw0lxsQkeZCZAB73jKPaOQk8JuVx7gSo1RqZAnLTxEXkZBZAczRXJ2d91zu52ZBh7amtucQSjZCVpMuyIkr0qbBCiz1QZDZD&__previous=1","next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.6\/290805814352519\/feed?limit=1&access_token=app_id|secret_key&until=1464088479&__paging_token=enc_AdDbZCIZC3RToSKiDH1DKImBZBQ5Rw0lxsQkeZCZAB73jKPaOQk8JuVx7gSo1RqZAnLTxEXkZBZAczRXJ2d91zu52ZBh7amtucQSjZCVpMuyIkr0qbBCiz1QZDZD"}}
```

Comment: Can you share the JSON you are getting in Pastebin or somewhere?

Comment: There is post image but i can't get it as result

Comment: Can't get it as results? How are you parsing it?

Comment: Try replacing /feed by /posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an App Access Token:

```
$page = 'page-id';
$accessToken = APP_ID . '|' . APP_SECRET;
$data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page . '/feed?access_token=' . $accessToken);
```

Also, you need to specify the fields you want to get:

```
/page-id/feed?fields=message&access_token=xxx
```

Information about the possible fields can be found in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/post

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: "not working" is not a sufficient error description. please read the part about the "fields" parameter too.